# Alternative to clicklistener inside an anonymous class

Tags: java, event-handling, libgdx

For a trivial word game, I wrote the following code for the player to choose one of the two choices of words that in turn were read from a sentence.

My question lies in first in the click-listener of the buttons of the choice.

The main code, in Java:

```
private void initAnswerButtons() {

    //2. here
    if (questionNum == wordList.size()){
        return; 
    }
    String s = wordList.get(questionNum);
    String[] choices = s.split("/");
    int numOfChoices = choices.length;          
    for (int i=0; i<numOfChoices ; i++)            
    {
        choiceButton[i] = new TextButton(choices[i], skin, "default");
        choiceButton[i].setPosition( 20 + i*120, app.camera.viewportHeight - 200);
        choiceButton[i].setSize(100, 50);
        choiceButton[i].addListener(new ClickListener() {

            //1. here
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                if (questionNum == wordList.size()){
                    return;
                }
                questionNum++;
                initAnswerButtons();
            }
       });
       stage.addActor(choiceButton[i]);
    }

}
```

The `wordList` array which I have hard-coded for:

```
private void initWordlist() {
    wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordList.add("nyumba/humba");
    wordList.add("ya/za");
    wordList.add("mji/kijiji");
    wordList.add("yake/hiki");
    wordList.add("ni sa udongo/si sa mawe");
}
```

The first question (see "1.here"): I am using a click-listener which is in the form of an anonymous class. As a result, I check whether I have run out of questions, i.e. `if (questionNum == wordList.size())`. If NOT so, it goes to the next question i.e. `questionNum++` and then:

```
initAnswerButtons();
```

I callback the method itself, yes, recursively from inside the method. What would you do instead to avoid such a structure?

Second question: in order to avoid running out of questions and out of range of the `wordList` array, I put an `if`-check (see "2. here"). That doesn't look good either, but that is also a natural consequence of the present structure of the code.

So, what would you do instead?